# Finding out which higher level function is making lots of low level calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trace

I have a function that is being called more than a thousand times, slowing everything down. However, it is a low level function, and do not know which of my high level function is lopping and making these calls. How can i find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the low-level function is written in Ruby, reopen its class and use `alias_method_chain`:

```
class TheClass
  def low_level_with_debug_output
    puts "I am being called by #{caller.first.inspect}"
    low_level_without_debug_output
  end

  alias_method_chain :low_level, :debug_output
end
```

`alias_method_chain` is a Rails-ism.

If the low-level function is not written in Ruby, you may need to instead use ruby-debug or even gdb on the interpreter itself to get at the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! I did this, and it showed me the following error. Any idea what went wrong?

"Expected /Users/mingyeow/mrtweet/lib/formatter/user_formatter.rb to define Formatter::UserFormatter"

Comment: You may have reopened the class incorrectly? Without seeing all the code I can't be sure